# How to get my files using a secure connection (https)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to host my pictures in a secure server(https).
My app is using https in all webpages so I don't want to run into problems of
browsers saying that my webpage isn't safe.
And I was wondering if I can do this in Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage works just fine over HTTPS. Just retrieve pages from 'https://storage.googleapis.com' instead of from 'http://storage.googleapis.com'.

Note that there's one exception: you cannot use HTTPS for custom domain name buckets. So if you create the bucket 'example.com', you can access it at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/example.com' or at 'http://example.com' but **not** at 'https://example.com'

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you only need to type manually the https as protocol that it is going to work just fine.